# Calculating the current through a time-varying RLC series resonant circuit

Tags: passive-networks, matlab, time, resonator

As shown in the circuit below, an admittance \$Y\$ consists of a series resonant circuit \$Y_m\$ and an additional capacitance \$C_0\$ in parallel.

[image]

\$Y\$ is given by
\$Y = j \omega C_0 + Y_m = j \omega C_0 + \frac{1}{R_m + j \omega L_m + \frac{1}{j \omega C_m}}\$.

Thus, the current can usually be determined by \$I_0 = V_0 \cdot Y\$.

**Problem:**
However, in my case, this circuit is not an LTI (linear time-variant) system but an LTV system (linear time-variant) because of the resonance frequency of the series resonant circuit changes with time.

**Goal:**
My goal is to numerically calculate the current \$i_0(t)\$ in the time domain with e.g. Matlab.

**Approach:**
I took the frequency response of a simple damped harmonic oscillator

\$
G(f) = \frac{1}{1 - \left(\frac{f}{f_{res}}\right)^2 + j \frac{f}{f_{res} Q}}
\$

that can be used to describe \$Y\$

\$
Y =j \omega C_0 + j \frac{G(f) \cdot f}{Q R_m f_{res}}
\$

where \$Q\$ is the quality factor and \$f_{res}\$ is the resonance frequency.

Then I wrote a little simulation in Matlab where I tried to make use of my definition of \$Y\$ from above and where I replaced the \$f_{res}\$ by a sinusoidal/time-varying resonance frequency:

```
clc;
clear all;
close all;

% parameters
fres = 7424;
Rm = 401.2e3;
Lm = 9.08e3;
Cm = 50.6e-15;
C0 = 44e-12;
Q = 1/Rm*sqrt(Lm/Cm);

fs = 100e3;
Ts = 1/fs;

f0 = fres;
Vhat0 = 1;
Tsim = 10;
fx = 1;

% time vector
t = 0 : Ts : Tsim-Ts;

% fft length
NFFT = length(t);

% input voltage (time and frequency domain)
v0 = Vhat0 .* cos(2.*pi.*f0.*t);
V0 = fft(v0, NFFT);

% time-varying resonance frequency
fres_of_t = fres + cos(2.*pi.*fx.*t);

% time-varying admittance
G = 1./(1 - (f0./fres_of_t).^2 + j.*(f0./(fres_of_t.*Q)));
Ym = j .* G.*f0./(Q.*Rm.*fres_of_t);
Y = j.*2.*pi.*f0.*C0 + Ym;

% current in the frequency domain
I0 = V0 .* Y;

% plot current (frequency domain)
figure;
fplot = fs/2*linspace(-1,1,NFFT);
I0Plot = abs(fftshift(I0)) ./ NFFT;

semilogy(fplot, I0Plot);
grid on;
xlabel('Frequency [Hz]');
ylabel('I_0 [A]');
```

[image]
[image]

Plotting the calculated current in the frequency domain shows the expected peak at the frequency of \$v_0\$ of 7424 Hz (\$=f_{res}\$). However, due to the time-varying resonance frequency, I would have expected both AM and PM modulation which should be visible by additional sidebands at \$\pm 1~\mathrm{Hz}\$ around the visible carrier signal.

I assume that my approach is totally wrong because I am treating an LTV like an LTI system but I am not really sure. Maybe anyone can give me a hint on how to solve my problem.

Comment: The FFT can only be calculated for one point of the variable f_res, so if you want to see how it affects the whole system then you need to perform as many FFTs as the f_res vector would have (or is chosen by you). Any non-LTI system can only have an FFT for one and only one value of its variations in time. For any other such values there must be other FFTs. Think of it as the equivalent of `.step` in SPICE.

Comment: However, if I calculate an FFT for each individual resonance frequency, I do not get a modulated time signal that I can demodulate again. I need a way to calculate a modulated current in the time domain.

Comment: Therefore, the approach via the calculation of an FFT is probably wrong, which is why the entire calculation must be done directly in the time domain (I assume). Does anyone have an idea about this?

Comment: Then you're probably looking for a sweep, in which case you'll get the exact same signal back, only the system that generated needs to have its f_res varying exactly the same as before the FFT. So, FFT is not relevant, as expected for non-LTI, except if you take "slices", as suggested. Don't forget that that sweep is not because the signal has a variable ferquency, it's because the system, itself, is varying. That's a whole lotta difference. At any rate, sicne you're interested in the current through a n-n-LTI, yes, time-domain is the way to go -- which, yet again, can be eased with "slices".